# How to create a virtual environment in Python using an environment.yaml file?

Tags: python, python-venv

I have a requirements.yaml file and I want to create a python virtual environment using it. The file looks like this

```
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.5
  - pip=19.3.1
  - pip:
    - jupyter==1.0.0
    - pandas==1.0.0
    - scikit-learn==0.22.1
    - numpy==1.18.1
    - matplotlib==3.1.3
    - seaborn==0.10.0
    - black==19.10b0
    - haversine==2.2.0
    - toml==0.10.0
    - nose==1.3.7
```

How can I use this file to create a new environment?

Comment: Are you using conda isn't?

Answer (score 6):

this looks like a conda environment (i could be wrong). In this case (if you have conda) you can do the following:

```
conda env create --name environment_name -f environment.yml
```

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

If you dont have or want Conda you would need to convert it to a requirements.txt

```
  - pip:
    - jupyter==1.0.0
    - pandas==1.0.0
    - scikit-learn==0.22.1
```

will look like that in the requirements.txt:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
pandas==1.0.0
scikit-learn==0.22.1
```

and then create and switch to your virtual environment

https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/

and then do

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: is there anyway not to do it with conda?

Comment: I described the way without conda in the answer. It starts with: "If you dont have or want Conda ..."

Comment: you but this is just requirements for python packages, I'm talking about defining python version and pip version in yaml, and create the env without conda. got it, otherwise everyone know how to use req.txt.

Comment: @mas u seem to be thinking what i was thinking - using yaml files possibly with `venv` and `pip`. But reading docs for [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli_interface.html#creator) & not finding any mention of specification/requirements file, i realised that `venv` for *virtual environment* and `pip` for *package installation* are two different things from official python's infrastructure PoV - it's just that `conda` or [`micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html#specification-files) conveniently provides both capabilities together.

Comment: I don't want to use conda people

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using conda your `env.yml` should look like

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.5
  - pip=19.3.1
  - pip:
    - jupyter==1.0.0
    - pandas==1.0.0
    - scikit-learn==0.22.1
    - numpy==1.18.1
    - matplotlib==3.1.3
    - seaborn==0.10.0
    - black==19.10b0
    - haversine==2.2.0
    - toml==0.10.0
    - nose==1.3.7
```

and in order to load it you need to run the following from the terminal.

```sh
conda env create -f env.yml
```

Few more suggestions.

- If you already have your environment, and you are within it, you can export via

```sh
conda env export | grep -v "^prefix: " > env.yml
```

- Please consider using a conda only environment and not a conda + pip one if it is possible. In your case all packages are available in conda.

Comment: I don't want to use conda