# How to generate a environments.yml file of a Python virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-venv

I want to generate a `environments.yml` file of an existing Python environment. I tried the following command:

```
python env export --from-history -f environment.yml
```

This throws the following error:

```
can't open file 'env': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Note: This is not a conda environment.

Comment: For the inverse of this: [How to create a virtual environment in Python using an environment.yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104229/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-in-python-using-an-environment-yaml-file)

Comment: No, I already have a python project. I want the environments.yml file to replicate it in a different machine

Comment: you can't use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`?

Comment: Note that I didn't claim your question is a duplicate. I mentioned that the link above is the ***inverse*** of your question. i.e.creating a venv from the yml. It's just useful to link similar questions together...

Comment: I did that now @Anu Thanks a lot.. post it as an answer, I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save the venv

`pip install -r requirements.txt` to create venv.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```